# Instance name is null - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, instance

I recently checked this in my SQL server instances:

SQL Server 2012 EE:

```
-- get current SQL Server name\instance name
  SELECT @@SERVERNAME
-- get current machine name and instance name
  SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName'), SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName')
```

And the results show NULL value for instance name for some of the instances.

I did go through [Instance name NULL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303774)

Sample output for one of my servers for `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName'), SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName')`

was

**'Class024.dev.com', Null**

Should I change the Instance name? Is it necessary or does it returns NULL if the instance is the default one?

Comment: Did you performed any of these actions that leads you to NULL Server Name? 1. The computer was renamed.
2. An image was taken of the SQL Server computer, and then copied onto another computer.
3. The sp_dropserver stored procedure was run for the local SERVERNAME. ?

Comment: I dont remember exactly. But there are chances that the image was copied onto another computer..

Comment: As Microsoft confirmed that this a BUG in SQL Server if you have performed any of the above actions. Go ahead with update

Comment: This requires a restart, if it is not much necessary then I can leave as it is. Is it mandatory?

Comment: restart is mandatory to take effect of the change, secondly this change is not valid for virtual servers. One more thing I am not sure about the effect of this change on Linked Servers.

Comment: [`InstanceName` will return `NULL` for default instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx). Can you show some actual examples of `@@SERVERNAME` where `InstanceName` returns `NULL`?

Comment: No what I mean should I implement the changes as mentioned to change the null value to the actual value? Is the change necessary in the first place?

Comment: @AaronBertrand wil this change require any type of update for Linked Server?

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding *what change we're talking about*. From what I know so far, my guess is that `InstanceName` is `NULL` because these are *not named instances*. How would you change that?

Comment: This question lacks enough detail to get any actual help with. It is not even stated what the expected instance name would be. Please update the question to state clearly what you are expecting the **ServerName\InstanceName** value to be, as well as the output from this query: `SELECT name, data_source, @@SERVERNAME AS [@@SERVERNAME], SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [MachineName], SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName') AS [InstanceName] FROM sys.servers WHERE server_id = 0;`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does return 'Null' if you've only got a default instance. I tried it in SQL 2005 and SQL 2008R2.
Otherwise, `@@SERVERNAME` should be the same as `ServerProperty('MachineName') + '\' + ServerProperty('InstanceName')`
Tested this also in SQL 2005 and SQL 2008R2.